# Filtering more than one column with more than one column in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across a scenario where I need to filter rows based on a combination of values. Let me explain using an example:

I have 2 tables as shown here:

[image]

For easy structuring I am including the T-SQL statements:

```
create table employees
(
    empId int,
    empname varchar(100),
    empSalary money
)

insert into employees 
values (1, 'John', 8000), (2, 'Sam', 9800), (3, 'Ray', 9500)

create table empLocations
(
    locId int,
    empId int
)

insert into empLocations 
values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1)
```

I wish to get (without cross joins) the rows of employees who stays in location 1 and 4 (locIds).

In this example it should return John and Ray.

Please note there are many conditions I am checking here and the location wise filtering is optional. Hence the structure of query should be

```
declare @locationIds varchar(100) = '1,4'

select * 
from employees 
where 
    (0 = case when (@locationIds is null) then 0 else 1 end) 
     or 
     ---<here goes the condition>-----  in (select strg from [dbo].[SplitStringi] (@locationIds,',') ) 
    )
```

Please note in the above example I have used a function to return values from comma separated values as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringi]       
    (@str nvarchar(4000),       
     @separator char(1))      
RETURNS TABLE
AS      
   RETURN (      
       WITH tokens(p, a, b) AS 
       (
           SELECT
               1, 1,       
               CHARINDEX(@separator, @str)      
           UNION ALL
           SELECT
               p + 1, b + 1,       
               CHARINDEX(@separator, @str, b + 1)      
           FROM tokens      
           WHERE b > 0      
        )      
        SELECT
            p indx,      
            SUBSTRING(@str, a,       
                      CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN b-a ELSE 4000 END) AS strg      
        FROM tokens      
      )
```

Comment: What SQL Server version are you running?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Aside: `(0 = case when (@locationIds is null) then 0 else 1 end)`? Is `@locationIds is null` too simple?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2019, you can use the built-in `STRING_SPLIT` function instead of a custom function to split strings.

This refactored example uses `STRING_SPLIT` and simplifies the check for the optional parameter. Additionally, the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint will eliminate the `IN` predicate from the query plan at compile time when the location list is `NULL`.

```
DECLARE @locationIds varchar(100) = '1,4';

SELECT * 
FROM employees AS e
WHERE 
    @locationIds is null
    OR e.empId IN (
        SELECT el.empId
        FROM empLocations AS el
        JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@locationIds,',') AS locs ON locs.value = el.locId
        WHERE el.empId = e.empId
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: could you check my answer too. are there any issues in it?

Comment: @Surensiveaya, I see no issues with that query but I recommend you use the more efficient `STRING_SPLIT` and `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for performance.

Comment: Personally would consider refactoring into a `UNION ALL` style query to avoid issues with the `OR` but needs looking at the query plan first

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
declare @locationIds varchar(100)='1,4'
select * from employees 
where
(
(0 = CASE WHEN (@locationIds is null) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
 or 
(employees.empId  in
 (select empid from  empLocations where locId in( select strg from [dbo].[SplitStringi] (@locationIds,',') ))
)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows :

```
select e.* 
from employees e
inner join empLocations el on e.empId = el.empId
where 
    (0 = case when (@locationIds is null) then 0 else 1 end) 
    or 
    (el.locId in (select value from string_split(@locationIds, ','))
     and el.locId in (select value from string_split(@locationIds, ','))
    );
```

Here is [a working demo in SQL Server 2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/g37G7nTd)

This gives you expected output as :

```
|empId| empname |empSalary |
|1    |  John   |  8000.00 |
|3    |  Ray    |  9500.00 |
```

Here is a more simplified query :

```
declare @locationIds varchar(100) = '1,4'

    SELECT e.*
    FROM employees e
    INNER JOIN empLocations el ON e.empId = el.empId
    WHERE @locationIds IS NULL OR el.locId IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@locationIds, ','));
```

Working [demo using DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zbnbYTCv)